# Error in registration form code

Tags: c#

I'm creating a registration form using using Visual Studio 2015, but when I run my code some problem occurs. I receive the error as stated bellow:

[image: Error Description]

I could not found the problem with my code:

```
private void execution(string RNumber, string fname, string lname, string Password, string Gender, string CPassword, string Email)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Table(RNumber, fname, lname, Password, Gender, CPassword, Email) VALUES "
    + " (@RNumber, @fname, @lname, @Password, @Gender, @CPassword, @Email)";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] pram = new SqlParameter[7];
        pram[0] = new SqlParameter("@RNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        pram[1] = new SqlParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        pram[2] = new SqlParameter("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        pram[3] = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        pram[4] = new SqlParameter("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        pram[5] = new SqlParameter("@CPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        pram[6] = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        pram[0].Value = RNumber;
        pram[1].Value = fname;
        pram[2].Value = lname;
        pram[3].Value = Password;
        pram[4].Value = Gender;
        pram[5].Value = CPassword;
        pram[6].Value = Email;
        for (int i = 0; i < pram.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pram[i]);
        }
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex_msg)
    {
        string msg = "Error occured while inserting";
        msg += ex_msg.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Here will be fially elements
        conn.Close();
    }

}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
}


protected void Buttonsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBoxregstr.Text == "")
    {
        Response.Write("Please complete the form.");
    }
    else
    {
        execution(TextBoxregstr.Text, TextBoxfirst.Text, TextBoxlast.Text, TextBoxpswrd.Text, TextBoxcnfrmpswrd.Text, TextBoxgender.Text, TextBoxemail.Text);
        Confirm.Visible = true;
        TextBoxfirst.Text = "";
        TextBoxlast.Text = "";
        TextBoxpswrd.Text = "";
        TextBoxgender.Text = "";
        TextBoxcnfrmpswrd.Text = "";
        TextBoxemail.Text = "";
        TextBoxregstr.Text = "";

    }
}
```

Comment: verify your table name in which you are going to insert. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates,

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

It  happens because **TABLE** is a [`reserved keyword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) for T-SQL. your query should enclose TABLE in `square` brackets

```
 string sql = "INSERT INTO [Table]
```

Better way to handle is you change the name and use a more descriptive word  for the table